# While function in guessing game keeps looping, python

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm a beginner in Python and I was wondering why this keeps looping, can someone help me out. When I print it out, it stays in a loop even tho I guessed the number right

```
import random

answer = random.randint(1,10)
lives = 5
out_of_lives = 0

print("Hi there! What is your name? ")
name = input()

print("Alright " + name + ", we're playing guess the number between 0 and 20.")

guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
while (lives != 0) or (guess != answer):
    if guess > answer:
        print("Guess lower!")
        lives = lives - 1
        print("You have got", lives, "lives left")
        guess = int(input('Try again, your new guess: '))
    elif guess < answer:
        print("Guess higher")
        lives = lives - 1
        print("You have got", lives , "lives left")
        guess = int(input('Try again, your new guess: '))
    elif guess == answer:
        print("Good job, you guessed the number")
    elif lives == 0:
        print("Game over!, I was thinking about the number: ", answer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not breaking the while loop.

One way to solve your problem is by inserting the conditions whether the user guessed the right number inside a main if condition of the guess is not the answer. And then break the loop when the user succeed. Like the following:

```
import random

answer = random.randint(1,10)
lives = 5
out_of_lives = 0

print("Hi there! What is your name? ")
name = input()

print("Alright " + name + ", we're playing guess the number between 0 and 20.")

guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
while (lives > 1):
   if guess != answer:
       if guess > answer:
           print("Guess lower!")
           lives = lives - 1
           print("You have got", lives, "lives left")
           guess = int(input('Try again, your new guess: '))
       elif guess < answer:
           print("Guess higher")
           lives = lives - 1
           print("You have got", lives , "lives left")
           guess = int(input('Try again, your new guess: '))
   else:
       print("Good job, you guessed the number")
       break

print("Game over!, I was thinking about the number: ", answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes this is because you also need to break the loop  just where you want it to stop.

Answer (score 0):

On the condition that the game is won, no adjustment to life or answers is set meaning you get stuck in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the conditions of your while loop. You wrote that "Keep going if you have lives remain or you are wrong". So it will not stop when you still have lives even if you guessed correct, or it will not stop writing "Game over" as you did not guessed right. The right thing to do is to change the loop condition as: `while (lives !=0) and (guess != answer):`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct code. Execute it. It'll solve your issue

```
import random

answer = random.randint(1,10)
lives = 5
out_of_lives = 0

print("Hi there! What is your name? ")
name = input()

print("Alright " + name + ", we're playing guess the number between 0 and 20.")

guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
while(True):
    
    if(lives==1):
        print("Game over!, I was thinking about the number: ", answer)
        break
    else:
        if guess == answer:
            print("Good job, you guessed the number")
            break
        elif guess > answer:
            print("Guess lower!")
            lives = lives - 1
            print("You have got", lives, "lives left")
            guess = int(input('Try again, your new guess: '))
        elif guess < answer:
            print("Guess higher")
            lives = lives - 1
            print("You have got", lives , "lives left")
            guess = int(input('Try again, your new guess: '))
```